# How to correctly sort data returned from XML file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sorting

which i want sort in ascending order by the DATE after this ajax call

```
function parseXML(xml){

    var weatherArray = [];
    var weatherElement = xml.getElementsByTagName("forecast")[0];
    weatherArray.queryTime = weatherElement.getAttribute("queryTime");
    weatherArray.queryLocation = weatherElement.getAttribute("queryLocation");
    weatherArray.weatherList = [];


    function s(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) - parseInt(b.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
        var weatherElements = weatherElement.getElementsByTagName("weather");
        weatherElements=weatherElements.sort(s);

    for(var i=0; i< weatherElements.length; i++){
        var weather = {};
        weather.year = Number(weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        weather.month = Number(weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("month")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        weather.date = Number(weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        weather.dayOfWeek = weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("dayOfWeek")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        weather.overall = weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("overall")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        weather.overallCode = weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("overallCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        weather.highest = Number(weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("highest")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        weather.lowest = Number(weatherElements[i].getElementsByTagName("lowest")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        weatherArray.weatherList.push(weather);
    }
    return weatherArray;
}
```

So that when the data appears in the browser it starts with the row of data showing the record from the DATE 26 first then 27 second and 28 ..... there's more repeat data in xml which i didnt include all in here.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
var weatherElements = [];
var weatherElementsArr = weatherElement.getElementsByTagName("weather");

for (var i in weatherElementsArr) {
    if (weatherElementsArr[i].nodeType == 1) {
        weatherElements.push(weatherElementsArr[i]);
    }
}

weatherElements.sort(s);
```

The problem was here:

```
var weatherElements = weatherElement.getElementsByTagName("weather");
    weatherElements=weatherElements.sort(s);
```

The value of `weatherElements` was an `HTMLCollection` which you can not sort on because it is not an native javascript array. It is a collection of HTML elements.

By creating an array with node elements you can now sort thru them as originally expected.